# Retornar em uma div específica da view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view

Tenho uma view onde o form de contato está no final da página, com validação via DataAnnotations. Quando clico no botão de enviar, no controller é feita a verificação do ModelState, se não for válido, ele retorna para a view com as mensagens de validação. 
Porém, ele retorna no começo da página(view) e como o form de contato está no final da página, teria que scrollar até o contato para ver as mensagens.
No caso, estou usando o scrollspy do bootstrap e gostaria de saber se tem como, no momento de retornar a view, retornar exatamente na div de contato, para retornar diretamente nas mensagens de erro.

Comment: Nunca testei esse scrollpsy, mas se no action do form você adicionar algo como `action="~/Gravar#formId"` não funciona?

Comment: JamesTK, no caso, como estou usando mvc não preciso definir a action do form, mas mesmo assim não daria resultado, pois o Controller retorna a view da página e eu não posso passar o id da div como parametro nesse return view();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pegue o *id* da `div` que foi validada os campos e coloque nesse comando:

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#IdDiv').offset().top }, 'slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Se eu bem entendi como funciona o Scrollspy, ele rola sozinho para uma determinada `<div>` ao clicar em um botão quando o documento está pronto (`$(document).ready()`). A informação de validação é gerado por um `Helper` no Razor (`@Html.ValidationSummary()`). Assim sendo, para obter o que você quer, o seguinte código deve resolver:

```
<div class="div-do-scrollspy">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Cigano, a validação eu consegui fazer, o problema é que quando a validação é feita, o Controller retorna a view porém no topo, não na div de contato no final da página, mas se eu scrollar as validações estão lá e eu não posso passar o id da div como parametro na return view(); do Controller

Comment: @FernandoBigal Você pode passar por `ViewBag`.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, consegui fazer da seguinte maneira:

Passei um valor por ViewBag como o Cigano Morrison Mendez falou, e no Javascript usei o método que o Tiago Falcão mencionou.
Agora quando a página carrega eu verifico se tem o valor na viewbag (que recebe só qnd tem a validação) e só então executa a função js